# Error with simple "Hello World" with Bash

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu-18.04

I have the following error

`bash: ./helloworld.sh: No such file or directory`

while executing the following Bash script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
#this is a helloworld programme
echo" hello world"
```

I checked this bash and it is correct

Comment: It seems that you are executing a script from a different directory

Comment: Also you have an error on the third line. You must add a space after the `echo`

Comment: Also make sure `bash` is really in `/usr/bin`; `type bash` will tell you where it is.

Comment: Thanks Alloces, i have rechecked when checked the directory which i have created this file when i checked ls-lrt , total is showing as 0. i am notsure where did the file go

Comment: You could check with `pwd` command to ensure where you work with  the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you try to run following: `echo "hello world"`, but you wrote `echo" hello world"`, which is same as `"echo hello world"`. Spaces are important.

But also looks like you are also running a wrong script...